# How to get a keyword using value i.e Title in Tridion core service?

Tags: core-service, sdl-tridion

*** to get keyword Id using keyword value?***

Answer (score 3):

Well, without giving too much of a solution, you will need to learn to use Core Service API. For that, hopefully, you already have a link to documentation.
But in general, here is the high-level tasks which you need to code:

1. get List of all CCategories in an (i guess) Publication. 
   For this you will need to use Filters, to get them.
2. Then for each category, get all the keywords in them. For this you can reference this question:
   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12072275/how-to-get-the-keywords-inside-the-category
3. and then use the standard filtering to match by title

Answer (score 3):

Following Marko's example of not giving you the exact code, I can propose a different approach. You could utilize the `TaxonomiesOwlFilterData` class which returns the entire taxonomy in one response in the [OWL format](https://www.w3.org/TR/owl-xmlsyntax/) (which is basically an XML). That way you do not need to check keyword by keyword but instead search within the xml to find what you're looking for.